# why I am getting different CGFloat value in different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Hi my CGFloat value shows different value according to device .

I am using cocos2d game for iPhone

I am trying to print **dt** value

In iPhone 5 it shows 0.0166666675

But in iPhone 6 it show 5.0176358830256065E-315

I am using this code

```
-(void)update:(CGFloat)dt {
static CGFloat time = 0;
time += dt;
 if (time >= 3) {
    [self unscheduleUpdate];
    time = 0;
    if ([self getChildByTag:999].visible)
    {
        [self hideGuide];
    }
} }
```

Comment: You have multiple `CGFloat` values shown in the code - which one is confusing you?

Comment: what results have you print  ? is it result of `time` ? or `dt` ? and what this `dt` parameter ? is it related to device time or date?

Comment: I am printed dt value

Comment: Does it print that value every time or only once? note that the value it is pretty damn close to `0`. @Lion `dt` is the delta time, the time passed since the last time the `update` method got called.

Comment: am assuming this is a real device (aka not simulator) and you `print` with NSLog ( not Xcode's debug values) ?

Comment: @ YvesLeBorg  I am using real device and it is Xcode's debug value.

Comment: @luk2302 The printed value every time same.

Answer (score 0):

You got different results because CGFloat value is different for 32bit & 64bit devices,

```
typedef float CGFloat;// 32-bit
typedef double CGFloat;// 64-bit
```

I think this will help you